# Was ist ein Slangwort dafür, dass jemand etwas sehr intensiv / zu viel tut?

Tags: word-usage

Ich bin aus Kroatien, habe nie in einer deutschsprachigen Region gelebt, aber finde deutsch faszinierend! Ich bitte um Verzeihung für mögliche Fehler. Ich möchte gern ein Phänomen aus dem Kroatischen ins Deutsche übertragen. Zum Beispiel, wenn ich nach Deutschland komme, will ich eine Situation auf eine kroatische Weise, aber mit deutschen Worten beschreiben.

Konkret suche ich ein "Straßenwort" dafür, dass jemand etwas sehr intensiv tut, möglicherweise zu viel. Mit "Straßenwort" meine ich ein Wort, das nicht im Wörterbuch sein muss.

Im Kroatischen gibt es dafür zum Beispiel folgende Straßenwörter:

1. *Gazi se* (engl. He steps over himself) - "Er tritt im Diskuswerfen über sich"
2. *Toviti se* (engl. *fatten up*) - "Er mästet sich im Diskuswerfen" (mästen)
3. *Drobiti* (engl. *grind*) - "Er zermahlt sich im Diskuswerfen" (zermahlen)
4. *Zgnječiti se* (engl. *crush*) - "Er zerquetscht sich im Diskuswerfen" (zerquetschen)

Also, benutzt oder kennt jemand so ein Wort? Danke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Beim Diskuswerfen überschlägt er sich

ist eine etwas analoge deutsche Formulierung aber riecht nicht sonderlich nach Straße.

Üblicher wäre aber wohl

> Er verausgabt sich total beim Diskurswerfen.

und auch nicht Straßenjargon.

> Das Diskuswerfen frisst ihn auf.

> Das Diskuswerfen verzehrt ihn.

sind auch gängige Metaphern.

Comment: Überschlägt ist ein Wort dass ~90% passt. Danke vielmals!

Answer (score 2):

Ein informelles Verb, das man verwenden kann, um auszudrücken, dass sich jemand mit einer Tätigkeit überanstrengt, lautet *sich kaputtmachen*

Analog zu deinem Beispiel wäre

> Er macht sich mit Diskuswerfen kaputt.

Allerdings ist das nicht besonders gebräuchlich. Es ist zwar eine informelle Sprechweise, aber nicht unbedingt ein Slangwort. *sich kaputtmachen* wird vor Allem in der Negation als ironische Untertreibung verwendet:

> Er macht sich auf Arbeit nicht gerade kaputt.

bedeutet soviel wie: "Er ist faul."

Insgesamt denke ich, dass der  deutsche Slang in dieser Frage nicht so reichhaltig ist wie offenbar der kroatische. Es kann aber gut sein, dass es in der Jugendsprache noch weitere Möglichkeiten gibt.

Comment: Kaputtmachen ist in meiner Meinung das Wort, das am besten passt, von allen die ich bis jetzt gehört habe. Der Grund ist dass man SICH von etwas kaputt machen kann. Ich werde noch ein bisschen warten, aber wenn kein besseres Wort herauskommt akzeptiere ich diese Antwort als korrekt.

Answer (score 2):

Im informellen Deutsch könnte man hier die Wendung benutzen, dass jemand etwas *wie ein Verrückter* betreibt.

Also im gegebenen Beispiel:

> Er macht Diskuswerfen wie ein Verrückter.

In einem formalen Kontext bietet sich *exzessiv* oder auch *bis zum Exzess* an:

> Er betreibt das Diskuswerfen exzessiv.

Answer (score 2):

Gerade in der Gamerszene ist *grinden*  ([ɡraɪnd(ə)n]) als eingedeutschtes Verb aus dem Englischen bekannt, mit der Bedeutung, eine gleiche Tätigkeit sehr intensiv zu wiederholen (nicht zu verwechseln mit dem Skatetrick).

> Er ist jeden Tag auf dem Feld und grindet seine Wurftechnik

Andere auch über die Gamerszene hinaus bekannte Formulierungen wären

> Er atmet förmlich Diskuswerfen.

> Er lebt fürs Diskuswerfen.

Comment: Jedoch dieses Wort sehr gut passt für die Situation die du erwähnt hast bin ich der Meinung dass dieses Wort im Kontext wenn mann im etwas besser sein will benutzt, und nicht wenn mann etwas zu viel macht. Auf Kroatisch würde mann sagen - Ich will diese Fähigkeit aus-schärfen (wie ein Mässer). Ich suche einen Satz der die folgende Reinfolge hat: er/sie _______ (Verb) sich im ________ (Aktion). Ich weiss nicht ob: "er grindet sich im Call Of Duty spielen" meint dass er dass zu viel macht - ich würde früher sagen dass in diesem Fall er sich verbessern will.

Comment: Gerade bei PC-Spielen gibt es auch den "Grind-Faktor". Wenn man zum Beispiel noch nicht ein bestimmtes Level erreicht hat, und deswegen (relativ monoton) schwächere Gegner tötet, um letztendlich aufzuleveln. Grind hat hier eher eine negative Konnotation.

Answer (score 0):

Ein paar weitere Vorschläge:

> Er fährt voll drauf ab / Er fährt voll auf xxx ab.

> Er geht voll in xxx auf / Er geht voll beim xxx auf.

> Er betreibt (oder macht) xxx wie ein Besessener

Answer (score 0):

Anbei einige reflexive Verbformen für:
"er/sie _______ (Verb) sich im ________ (Aktion) // Diskuswerfen"

- schindet
- verausgabt
- rackert ... ab
- quält ... ab
- reibt ... auf
- plagt ... ab
- martert ... ab
- malträtiert
- (ver-)schleisst
- killt
- drillt